# FreeBSD ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, freebsd

Can not start mysql .. 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can not connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock (2)

I use mysql51. I've tried reinstalling but nothing works ...

Comment: mysql is not running, or the mysql socket file is not in /tmp

Comment: in the output of `ps ax`, do you see the mysqld process?

Comment: Yes, mysql is not running and I do not have mysql.sock 
No fvu, I do not have the process.

Answer (score 1):

After installing MySQL for the first time run:

```
mysql_install_db --user=mysql
```

and

```
mysqld_safe &
```

and setup your root password with:

```
/usr/local/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'your_passwd'
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) has pointed out in the comments, `mysql` is not running.

In console (as root/admin), type;

```
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server start
```

This should start the service, and you should be good to go.

#### [Source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/freebsd-start-stop-restart-mysql-server/)

Comment: root@:/usr/ports/databases/mysql51-server # 
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server start
Starting mysql.

root@:/usr/ports/databases/mysql51-server # /usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server status
mysql is not running.

Comment: Have you added `mysql_enable="YES"` to /etc/rc.conf ?

Comment: Have a look in the MySQL error log, and see if it gives any hints

Comment: My .err file, I have nothing at all

Comment: @hd. Since FreeBSD 7.3 the [`service`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?service%288%29) command is available to make things easier, as in `service mysql-server start`.

Answer (score 0):

Try following command line:

```
sudo chown -R _mysql:mysql /usr/local/var/mysql
sudo mysql.server start
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise this very non-technical solution will not be appropriate for many users but I fixed this exact error by installing an earlier version of MySQL, and am posting this since had I been able to read that here, it would have saved me hours of trying everyone else's solutions that did not work at all for me.

Mysql seems to allow you to install pretty much any version regardless of whether it will work so look carefully at compatibility before installing.

NOTE: I installed version 8.0.22 as it said that versions for Catalina were compatible with Mojave. This did not work for me running Mac OSX 10.14.6 but installing 8.0.18 fixed this and it now runs smoothly.